# django multiple if else refactor

Tags: python, design-patterns, django, orm

I have a function with multiple if else statements that I'm trying to simplify in Django

Is there a pattern or maybe a better modeling approach that I could use here?

The idea behind is to have a thumbs up, thumbs down behavior for each blog post

views.py

```
@login_required
def blog_post_vote(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        vote = request.POST['vote']
        has_user_voted = BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user).count()
        if has_user_voted == 0:
            if vote == "yes":
                user_vote_yes = BlogPostUserVote(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_yes=1)
                user_vote_yes.save()
            if vote == "no":
                user_vote_no = BlogPostUserVote(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_no=1)
                user_vote_no.save()
        else:
            has_user_voted_yes = BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_yes=1).count()
            has_user_voted_no = BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_no=1).count()
            if vote == "yes" and has_user_voted_yes == 0:
                user_vote_yes = BlogPostUserVote(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_yes=1)
                user_vote_yes.save()
                BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_no=1).delete()
            if vote == "no" and has_user_voted_no == 0:
                user_vote_no = BlogPostUserVote(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_no=1)
                user_vote_no.save()
                BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user, vote_yes=1).delete()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # Slug = Short URL Label
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def thumbs_up(self):
        return BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=self).aggregate(Sum("vote_yes"))['vote_yes__sum']

    @property
    def thumbs_down(self):
        return BlogPostUserVote.objects.filter(blog_post=self).aggregate(Sum("vote_no"))['vote_no__sum']

    # This line is very important as it maps the objects to the default manager
    objects = BlogPostManager()

    # Ordering Newest to Oldest
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_date', '-updated', '-timestamp']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/blog/{self.slug}"


class BlogPostUserVote(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_yes = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    vote_no = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What are `has_user_voted` and friends?  Reading the variable name, I would think a boolean `True`/`False`.  But you keep checking if `==0` instead.

Comment: Hi, it is a query against the BlogPostUserVote table and if it finds any record with the given filter will return a number greather than 0. Not exactly a boolean though

Comment: Your title is too generic. Please read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

Well finally I ended up with the following, I changed some names to make it more explanatory and the function to respond to an ajax request. However the logic is pretty much the same:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def blog_post_reaction(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        reaction = json.loads(request.body)['vote']
        BlogPostUserReaction.objects.filter(blog_post=post, user=request.user).delete()
        new_user_reaction = BlogPostUserReaction(blog_post=post, user=request.user)
        if reaction == "upvote":
            new_user_reaction.upvote = 1
        if reaction == "downvote":
            new_user_reaction.downvote = 1
        if any((new_user_reaction.upvote, new_user_reaction.downvote)):
            new_user_reaction.save()
    return JsonResponse({'slug': slug, 'upvotes': post.upvote, 'downvotes': post.downvote})
```